# How to wait for an etcd variable is set before starting the unit/service

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos

I am currently working on logging with the ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) stack in an CoreOS cluster. I found out, you can use gelf to automatically send the logs from docker to logstash. I am using a sidekick to write a etcd variable of the logstash container IP address. Since I have to pass the IP of logstash to a flag in the docker run command I need to wait until the variable is set.

My question is how can I wait until `etcdctl get /network/logstash` returns the IP address.

This is how my unit-file looks at the moment:

```
[Unit]
Description=nginx with elk logging
After=logstash-discovery.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/systemctl set-environment ADDR=$(etcdctl get /network/logstash)"
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill nginx1
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm nginx1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull 10.0.2.2:5000/nginx
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -p 80:80 --name=nginx1 --net=host --log-driver=gelf --log-opt gelf-address=udp://${ADDR}:12201 --log-opt gelf-tag="fe" 10.0.2.2:5000/nginx
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop nginx1

[X-Fleet]
Conflicts=logstash.service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `etcdctl watch` instead of `etcdctl get` but checking before if the variable isn't already set.
So the full line looks like this:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c \
"if [ -z $(etcdctl get /network/logstash) ]; \
then /usr/bin/systemctl set-environment ADDR=$(etcdctl watch /network/logstash); \
else /usr/bin/systemctl set-environment ADDR=$(etcdctl get /network/logstash); \
fi"
```

Comment: I am also open for a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem boils down to a question about `bash` programming: How do you wait until a variable is set before proceeding?

A variation of that question is already answered at [How to create a loop in bash that is waiting for a webserver to respond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904772/how-to-create-a-loop-in-bash-that-is-waiting-for-a-webserver-to-respond).

This takes a bit more than one line of code usually, so you may need to put the logic in a file and point `ExecStartPre` to that instead of using a one-liner.

Comment: I had already something like that in ExecStartPre but nothing changed. It was a while loop: while ${ADDR} == "" or is it an other value when ${ADDR} is empty