# While cURL is downloading execute stopwatch script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, while-loop

I have some sort of stopwatch script that looks like:

```
BEGIN=$(date +%s)

while true; do
   NOW=$(date +%s)
   DIFF=$(($NOW - $BEGIN))
   MINS=$(($DIFF / 60))
   SECS=$(($DIFF % 60))
   HOURS=$(($DIFF / 3600))

   # \r  is a "carriage return" - returns cursor to start of line
   printf "\rDownload time: %02d:%02d:%02d" $HOURS $MINS $SECS
   sleep 1
done
```

So `while` some condition is true, it will keep adding 1 second per loop. I want this condition to be something along the lines:

```
function download()
{
    HOMEPAGE_RESPONSE=$(curl -w "\n%{http_code}" "https://example.com/")

    STATUS_CODE=$(echo "$HOMEPAGE_RESPONSE" | sed -n '$p')

    HTML=$(echo "$HOMEPAGE_RESPONSE" | sed '$d')
}

download

# Whenever the STATUS_CODE is 200, exit the stopwatch script
# Can be any other condition that stops the loop when cURL has finished
while (( $STATUS_CODE != 200 )); do
   NOW=$(date +%s)
   DIFF=$(($NOW - $BEGIN))
   MINS=$(($DIFF / 60))
   SECS=$(($DIFF % 60))
   HOURS=$(($DIFF / 3600))

   # \r  is a "carriage return" - returns cursor to start of line
   printf "\rDownload time: %02d:%02d:%02d" $HOURS $MINS $SECS
   sleep 1
done
```

The idea is to initiate the cURL download and at the same time the download starts, execute the stopwatch script. This will eventually start counting seconds and printing the stopwatch `until` the download is complete. I am also aware of the `until` command which I found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904772/how-to-create-a-loop-in-bash-that-is-waiting-for-a-webserver-to-respond). Example:

```
until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://myhost:myport); do
    printf '.'
    sleep 5
done
```

I don't know how to apply `until` since my cURL is stored in a variable within the function called `download()` and I want to be able to use the `STATUS_CODE` and the `HTML` content separately.

Can anyone tell me how I can do so?

---

**UPDATE**

Given @Inian 's answer this is what I have so far:

```
function download()
{
    homepage_response=$(curl -s -w "\n%{http_code}" "https://example.com/")
    status_code=$(echo "$homepage_response" | sed -n '$p')
    html=$(echo "$homepage_response" | sed '$d')
    printf '%s' "${status_code}"
}

# Calling the function $(download)
until [[ "$(download)" == "200" ]]; do
    printf '.\n'
    sleep 1
done

echo $status_code
```

According to my understanding, this should execute the function `download()` and print `.` each on a different line `until` cURL returns the `status_code` of `200`.

This, however, initiates cURL but neither it prints `.` nor does it echo the `status_code` which should be equivalent to `200`.

I cannot guess why.

---

**ALTERED ANSWER**

According to @chepner 's answer I came up with:

```
download()
{
    homepage_response=$(curl -s -w "\n%{http_code}" "https://example.com/")
    status_code=$(echo "$homepage_response" | sed -n '$p')
    html=$(echo "$homepage_response" | sed '$d')
    # printf '%s' "${status_code}"
}

start_stopwatch () {
    BEGIN=$(date +%s)
    while true; do
        NOW=$(date +%s)
        DIFF=$(($NOW - $BEGIN))
        MINS=$(($DIFF / 60))
        SECS=$(($DIFF % 60))
        HOURS=$(($DIFF / 3600))

        printf "\rDownload time: %02d:%02d:%02d" "$HOURS" "$MINS" "$SECS"
        sleep 1 & wait  # Make it interruptible
    done
}

start_stopwatch & sw_pid=$!

# # For testing purposes
# echo "$sw_pid"

# Kill background stopwatch if script EXITS beforehand
set -e
kill_sw() {
    kill "$sw_pid"
}
trap kill_sw EXIT

# Call function download()
download

printf "\n"

kill "$sw_pid"
```

Out of precaution I added `set -e` which calls the function `kill_sw()` whenever the script gets interrupted before `kill "$sw_pid"` is even executed at the end.

Comment: You don't need `let` if you are using the (preferred) `$((...))` syntax.

Comment: You might want to look into using the progress meter that `curl` already supplies instead.

Comment: You are right @chepner I removed the `let` from my code

Comment: I would like to avoid using the progress meter as I sometimes find it not entirely accurate. I simply want to implement a stopwatch of my own which executes parallel to the download and at the end shows the amount of time it has taken. @chepner I updated my question, could you guess why my last script is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run the stopwatch code in the background, and kill it once `curl` has completed.

```
start_stopwatch () {
   SECONDS=0
   while true; do
     now=$SECONDS
     hours=$((now / 3600))
     now=$((now % 3600))
     mins=$((now / 60))
     secs=$((now % 60))

     printf "\rDownload time: %02d:%02d:%02d" "$hours" "$mins" "$secs"
     sleep 1
   done
}

start_stopwatch & sw_pid=$! 
curl ...
kill "$sw_pid"
```

Comment: I adjusted your code a little, else it work like a charm. It's worth mentioning that for me your `while` did not work. It simply returns a static clock like `00:00:00`. I updated my question with the `while` that worked for me. Thanks @chepner !

Comment: Ugh, I meant `SECONDS`, not `RANDOM`. (Still not working, but I'll try to debug in a bit.)

Comment: OK, apparently you can't localize `$SECONDS`, or it loses its special powers. Just leave it as a global variable, and make sure `start_stopwatch` runs in a subshell if you care about the value of `SECONDS` in the current shell.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the function call into the `until` conditional. But the function `download()` in its current state is not printing the output of status code. With a small modification as below.

```
download() {
    homepage_response=$(curl -w "\n%{http_code}" "https://example.com/")    
    status_code=$(echo "$HOMEPAGE_RESPONSE" | sed -n '$p')
    html=$(echo "$HOMEPAGE_RESPONSE" | sed '$d')
    printf '%s' "${status_code}"
}
```

Now with the function printing the status code, use it in the conditional as

```
until [[ "$(download)" -eq "$(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://myhost:myport)" ]]; do
    sleep 1
    # Your rest of the script goes here
done
```

---

As a general coding practice,

1. You could use the arithmetic operator `((..))` over the `let` construct
2. Lower case user-defined variables to avoid conflicting them with `bash` system specific environment variables.
3. Function definition without the `function` keyword is recommended when thinking of porting the script without any `bash`-isms involved.

Comment: Hi @Inian , I updated my question according to your answer.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the syntax?