# Can Raspberry pi run 2 commands on startup with a delay in between them

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to fire 2 commands on startup on my raspberry pi

The first one runs a node server starting script.
The second one should open chromium browser with a specific page.

The point is that I want to wait a couple of seconds to launch chromium so I'm sure that the webpage will be connected to the node server.

I tried so many things but I can't seem to fix a the delay.

Any suggestions?

This is what I have now in an LXDE session:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash

// This starts the node server
@/home/pi/autostart.sh

// This starts the browser
@/home/pi/async.sh
```

The async bash runs this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 5
chromium-browser -kiosk http://localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You start the node server and loop until the site comes online before launching the web-browser. 
Replace "sleep 5" in async.sh by the following:

```
until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:3000); do
    printf '.'
    sleep 1
done
```

source : [How to create a loop in bash that is waiting for a webserver to respond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904772/how-to-create-a-loop-in-bash-that-is-waiting-for-a-webserver-to-respond)

Comment: And where do I trigger the chromium script?